# How to using SKEmitterNode effect to drawing like SKShapeNode does?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I want to make a drawing app by using SKEmitterNode effect.

I know that SKShapeNode are used to stroke or fill a CGPath and I can use SKShapeNode to do it,

But what I want is using SKEmitterNode effect like following images to do the same work.

Is it possible ?

[image: effect like this]

Answer (score 2):

Yes, and this is a very good use of SKEmitterNodes.

First, you'll need to use Additive blend mode on your particles to get this effect.

And you should then set the pace (motion) of the particles to 0 in all directions, and not have them impacted by gravity. When they're emitted, they should be stationary.

The particle emitter should move with the touch of the artist/user, and emit at a rate slightly inverse to the rate of change in position of the emitter.